# Do-While loop is exiting prematurely

Tags: java, loops, do-while, chess

I tried writing a PvP Chess program. However, when an invalid move is played, it ends the turn.

```
        do
        {
            boolean q = askMove(board, white , in);
            if (q == true){
                white.move = false;
                break;
            }
            else
                continue;
        } while (white.move == true);
        do
        {
            //boardDisplay (board);
            boolean w = askMove(board, black, in);
            if (w == true){
                black.move = false;
                break;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }while (black.move == true);
    }
```

In the code, q takes true, if the initial and final co-ordinates of a piece are not the same.

```
    if (x1 != x2 || y1 != y2)
            return true;
        return false;
```

When I execute this code,

[First move is made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FDsg.png)

So, if I play the 2nd invalid, the 2nd move should replay, because (q == false)
However,

The code should only trigger 'you can't move an enemy piece' only when it is the wrong player's turn. However, it triggers when I try to play a valid move as well.

[It says that I'm using an enemy piece!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIuQs.png)

Even though I wrote:

```
   player p
    if (board[x1][y1].initPiece.name.charAt(0) != p.colour)
        System.out.println ("you cannot move an enemy piece");
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: please format  your code.

Comment: What do you think `break;` is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much as it could be improved, I don't think your error is in the first block of code you've shown.

If it's really needed, `askMove()` could to set `white/black.move` to `false`.  Then you could simplify the first block of code as:

```
while(!askMove(board, white, in));
while(!askMove(board, black, in));
```

Which doesn't come close to explaining your error.

However, I think you will find your error quite quickly if you change this code:

```
    if (board[x1][y1].initPiece.name.charAt(0) != p.colour)
        System.out.println ("you cannot move an enemy piece");
```

To this code:

```
    if (board[x1][y1].initPiece.name.charAt(0) != p.colour)
        System.out.println ("You cannot move the enemy piece " 
            + board[x1][y1].initPiece.name + " at " 
            + x1 + "," + y1 + " when playing as "
            + p.colour);
```

I'd have to see the rest of your code but I wouldn't be surprised if the indexing is being reversed as players are switched.